# Display or download image through the browser

Tags: java, sockets, http

I have a server that displays what the user asks for from the browser, I am using linux and when i run the server and ask for a file like **Image.png** using this link `localhost:9999/Image.png` on FireFox i get this message:

> The image "localhost:9999/Image.png" cannot be displayed because it
>   contains errors.

But when i change the variable fileName to an HTML file it works perfectly and i can visualize the html page.

What am I doing wrong??

This is my server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
// Declarem les variables a utilitzar
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        InputStream inS = null;
        OutputStream outS = null;

        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
            while(true)
            {
                socket= serverSocket.accept();     
                inS = socket.getInputStream();
                outS = socket.getOutputStream();


                try{
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inS));
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outS));                   
                    System.out.println("THis is what the user wants = " + br.readLine());


                    String fileName = "Image.png";
                    String extension= "";
                    int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                    if (i > 0) {
                        extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
                    }
                    String dataReturn = "";
                    if(extension.equals("png"))
                    {

                        bw.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
                        bw.write("Content-Type: image/png\r\n");
                        bw.write("\r\n");
                        FileReader myFilepng = new FileReader(fileName);
                        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(myFilepng);
                        dataReturn = "";
                        while(scanner1.hasNextLine()) {
                             dataReturn = scanner1.nextLine();
                             System.out.println(dataReturn);
                             bw.write(dataReturn);
                        }
                            scanner1.close(); 

                    }else{
                        if(extension.equals("html"))
                        {
                            bw.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
                            bw.write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
                            bw.write("\r\n");
                            bw.write("<TITLE>"+fileName+"/TITLE>"); 

                            FileReader myFile = new FileReader(fileName);
                            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
                            dataReturn = "";
                            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                                dataReturn = scanner.nextLine();
                                System.out.println(dataReturn);
                                bw.write(dataReturn);
                            }
                            scanner.close();
                        }
                    }   

                    bw.close();

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
        }

        inS.close();
        outS.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are returning text with your html response, which is correct, but you are not returning the image contents for your png.

Comment: Where is the code to load the image data and write it to your `bw`?

Comment: I tried doing the same as i do in html case reading all the file content but it didnt work @BitExodus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not writing the contents of your png file to your bw BufferedWriter. Instead you are only sending the header of the response to the client. As you are indicating your response is a png image and there is no data, your browser is telling you the image contains errors (in fact, it does not contains nothing at all).

Open the png filename, write the data to your "bw" buffer to send it to the client. That should be enough.

Edit:

To to that, try the following code for your "if" is image:

```
if(extension.equals("png"))
{
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    fis.read(data);
    fis.close();

    DataOutputStream binaryOut = new DataOutputStream(outS);
    binaryOut.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
    binaryOut.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/png\r\n");
    binaryOut.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + data.length);
    binaryOut.writeBytes("\r\n\r\n");
    binaryOut.write(data);

    binaryOut.close();
}
```

Note the use of a binary stream in comparison to the text stream you use in case of html.

Comment: How can I read the image contents, because the sacnner only works for .txt or .html files, it didnt worked for me with .png file, it doesnt read anything???

Comment: Just read the file contents in your server and write to the bw. Then make the petition from your client. Another question: are you following the standard and separating the head from the body? Take a loot at https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html

Comment: I did but its still returning the same error (cannot be dsiplayed) see the changes above..

Comment: @PaulErdemBursh I have edited the answer to include the code example, give it a try.